# What will be the Query in my situation in Adobe CQ5

Tags: jackrabbit, aem, jcr, crx, jcr-sql2

Root contains one folder, named **pending** of type **sling:folder**.

That have numbers of nodes of **nt:unstructured** type, having name of long value, that long value is very important for my code processing.

Now I want to get top 20 nodes(20 minimum node name , i.e., long value) data from this **pending** folder.

Can you tell me how can I write the JCR query for this situation ?

**Edit No. 1**

```
Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository("http://localhost:4502/crx/server");
Session session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()));

// Obtain the query manager for the session via the workspace ...
QueryManager queryManager = session.getWorkspace().getQueryManager();    
// Create a query object ...

String expression = "SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS s WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE([/pending])";
Query query = queryManager.createQuery(expression, javax.jcr.query.Query.JCR_SQL2);

// Execute the query and get the results ...
QueryResult result = query.execute();

// Iterate over the nodes in the results ...

NodeIterator nodeIter = result.getNodes();
```

But it gives some order , different than the order present in root node. But that is not in sort form.

**Edit No.2**

Now I got the functionality of this function. And it working fine now. The thing that I got is order the node just above the destination node, that is mentioned in second parameter of this function.

But the nodes that is coming is of different names(a number). So how can I sort this using `orderBefore`. Because everytime we are not able to know the right location(destination Relative Path) where we have to put this node.

Comment: So the node *name* is a string of digits that can be interpreted as a long value?  Do I understand you correctly?  And you want to get the 20 nodes with names that correspond to the highest numerical values?

Comment: Yes exactly. I read on one blog that sling:orderedFolder helps in this case. Can you please help me in that.

Comment: @DavidGorsline Can you give me some guidance, please. In solving above problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need a query for this, if you have structure such as

```
/pending/1
/pending/2
...
/pending/999
```

you can just iterate over the nodes using the JCR Node's getNodes() method, which returns a  NodeIterator.

A sling:orderedFolder node type for "pending" gives a predictable ordering of the child nodes.

In general, using the tree structure instead of queries is more efficient in JCR.

Note also that if you're using Jackrabbit having more than about 10'000 child nodes on the same parent can lead to performance issues.

Comment: @BertrandDelacetaz I also uses `sling:OrderedFolder` but that didn't give me the ordered result set that you said to me.  See Edit No. 1

Comment: @devsda You mentioned in the original question that you're using `sling:folder` — have you changed the node type since then & are still not getting the desired result? Just want to clarify as there's a difference between `sling:folder` and `sling:orderedFolder`.

Comment: @anotherdave Yes first I used sling:folder, then from somewhere I got the concept of sling:orderedFolder. YEs I didn't get the desired result.

My main node is of sling:orderedFolder, and child node is of nt:unstructured type. I think now you are clear with my doubt .

Comment: @devsda & you're getting a different order every time you call `.getNodes()` on *pending*? Or you're getting a consistent order, but it's not the order you're expecting?

Comment: Yes I am getting consistent order, but that is not expected, after calling .getNodes().

Comment: @anotherdave When I make child nodes also of type `sling:orderdFolder` then also it gives the same order, as it is stored under the root.

Comment: @anotherdave Can we do a chat here please. I have one more doubt. I need your help in that.

Comment: An ordered folder will not sort the results when you call getNodes(), what it does is keep the order in which the nodes were inserted, and support the Node.orderBefore method. Does that explain what you're seeing?

Comment: @BertrandDelacretaz YEs I think it may work, But I didn't understand how to make module using this. Can you share the implementation guide for my case. I tried `Node root = session.getRootNode();
                    Node child = root.getNode("PendingURLsDB");
                    child.addNode("129").orderBefore("123", "123");` But it shows some problem. Please explain your suggested part. Waiting for your kind response.

Comment: "shows some problem" as a diagnostic won't allow someone to help you. You might want to start at http://jackrabbit.apache.org/first-hops.html and gradually morph that example into what you want.

Comment: @BertrandDelacretaz I implemented all the examples that is given in your given link. But When I try to implement `orderBefore` method and the documentation is given using very typical language. http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html#orderBefore(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Can you tell me about `srcChildRelPath` and `destChildRelPath` used in method orderBefore ? What it would be in my case ?

Comment: @BertrandDelacretaz See Edit No. 2.